# How to make API calls to Google Cloud Storage APIs without using Google Client Library. [NodeJS]

Tags: node.js, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I need to make REST calls to Google Cloud Storage for the following functions:

1. Authenticate. - That is generate access tokens from client credentials using OAuth 2.0.
2. Download an Object.
3. Upload an Object.

How can I make generic NodeJS API calls for the above request without using any third-party library (@google-cloud/storage)?
All the references and resources I see only point to using Client-Library [[Link]](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/)

References:
Google Cloud Storage Doc - [Link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)

Comment: Can you give a context of why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have a product using multiple file provider services as azure, google, s3, and many more thus having an abstract layer built on top of all this logic that needs to be generic for all others as well. that is why I need to do it using simple NodeJS GET, POST request and not any client library

Comment: [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api) and
 [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview) describe the API... isn't that all you need?

Comment: yes but does any resource have code examples or snippets for those API calls as they have here https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/ for client library

Comment: As Johannes commented, you can use json api and xml api, sharing the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-storage-docs-json-api-examples) and the [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-storage-docs-xml-api-examples/blob/master/storage-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/StorageServiceAccountSample.java) of the same. These are using Java but not Node.js. However, you may have a look on it to get an idea.